# How to get a value of an object's property when the property name is a variable itself in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, el

HI,

Here's my dilemma. The below code is obviously wrong but it give you the idea on what I need to accomplish.

```
<c:forEach var="object1" items="${model.listofObjects1}">
  <tr>
    <c:forEach var="object2" items="${model.listofObjects2}">
      <td>${object1.${object2}}</td>
    </c:forEach>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Any ideas on how to make this look up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the brace notation.

```
<td>${object1[object2]}</td>
```